# Does Authorize.Net CIM handle payments?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, authorize.net, authorize.net-cim

I am developing a site where i need to charge a customer according to usage say if user has opted for a $20/month plan for 200 mins  and he uses 200+ mins then he would be charged accordingly.

I am using the Customer Information manager API (CIM) for this and need to know how the payments are handled for the same. Does  Authorize.Net automatically charge the customers credit card and deduct the money from there account or only billing is done by CIM? means the CIM only does the billing and not the payment process and if only billing is done then do i need AIM for payment process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CIM does process payments. Whenever you want to charge your user to make an API call to CIM with their payment account ID and charge them whatever amount you specify. You would do this using the `createCustomerProfileTransactionRequest` API call.

Comment: do u mean to say that if the user is charged some amount then his account would be directly charged on a particular day of a month without getting the customer involved

Comment: You don't need to get the customer involved with CIM because once the payment profile is created you can charge against it whenever you want. If you want the account to be charged on a regularly scheduled basis you would need to create your own recurring billing engine as CIM does not do recurring billing on its own.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response really appreciate it.

Comment: now m planning to make a windows service to handle the recurring part or do i have other option

Comment: That sounds like a great way to do it to me. Good luck with it.